# Colab Pro+ CNN GPU memory saturation

Tags: keras, cnn, jupyter, colab

I have a problem when executing jupyter notebook for CNN in colab pro+, to train a model with a size of 560664x48x48x1.
normally the data is composed of images with a size of 48x48.
I used 10 fold cross-validation to train the model with the following code :
rom sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold

```
from datetime import datetime
from keras import backend as K
#here i will use stratifiedkfold cross validation method
##number of folds
kfold_splits=9
New_Data_train = np.reshape(New_Data_train , [560664,48, 48, 1])
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=kfold_splits, shuffle=True)
lst_accu_stratified = []
lst_loss_stratified = []
lst_history_stratified = []
# K-fold Cross Validation model evaluation
fold_no = 1
#the folder where i wante to save the models 
FOLDER = "CNN_models_09_08_2022"
for k_train_index, k_val_index in skf.split(New_Data_train, New_Y_target):
    # Generate batches from indices
    xtrain, xval = New_Data_train[k_train_index], New_Data_train[k_val_index]
    ytrain, yval = New_Y_target[k_train_index], New_Y_target[k_val_index]
    ##ici je reinitialise le model temporaire (getting the model of cnn)
    model_CNN = get_model()
    #j'entraine le modele
    h = model_CNN.fit(xtrain,ytrain, epochs=100,batch_size=128)
    # evaluate the model
    scores = model_CNN.evaluate(xval,yval, verbose=0)
    ##I save the CNN model for future use.
    model_CNN.save(FOLDER+"/CNN_UNSW_"+str(fold_no)+"_FOLD.h5")
    lst_accu_stratified.append(scores[1])
    lst_loss_stratified.append(scores[0])
    lst_history_stratified.append(h)
    fold_no = fold_no+1
    del model_CNN
    #clearing sesssion
    K.clear_session()
    print("-------------------------------------------------------")
```

after executing the code above colab pro+ crashes because of insufficient GPU Ram and
the following exception is raised :

```
InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

can someone explain to me how to optimize this code in order to avoid this exception because it doesn't pass the 3 folds of cross validation.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is [a known Keras problem](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9379) that calling `K.clear_session()` and deleting the model sometimes fails to clear the GPU allocated memory, and [this leads to the error you are seeing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40389498).

As a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52354943/674487), after clearing the session, you can force CUDA directly to release everything. For this, you can use [numba](https://github.com/numba/numba). The code to release the CUDA memory with numba is as follows:

```
from numba import cuda
cuda.select_device(0)
cuda.close()
```

Comment: thank you for your response but colab pro+ freezer after the cuda close and it didn't continue executing for the next fold validation. do you know why ? thank you.

Comment: Maybe try without the `cuda.select_device(0)` line.

Comment: it didn't work too. I tested many other solutions like this one but I have the same problem: https://maneeshkadanasseril.medium.com/cuda-error-out-of-memory-331d47d85414